# What to do when FreeLibrary API call fails?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dll, native

### Question

I have a third-party DLL that throws an unhandled exception when attempting to unload it from my native C application. This results in the call to [FreeLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) failing, and the module remaining loaded in my process.

**Are there any options to forceably unload the library?**

**What do you do when the FreeLibrary calls?**

### Additional Background

When using load-time dynamic linking this is annoying enough, but ultimately the application gets torn down by the OS. The problem comes when using run-time dynamic linking. I load up this DLL, use it, and then in some instances I need to unload it from my process's virtual address space and then continue running. When I call FreeLibrary on the third-party library, it does some cleanup work (i.e. in [DllMain when DLL_PROCESS_DETACH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is called). While it's doing it's cleanup, it causes an exception to be thrown which it doesn't handle, and bubbles up as an unhandled exception to FreeLibrary. This results in the call failing and the module remaining loaded.

I've put a ticket in with the vendor so hopefully I can get a fix which will allow this specific library to unload successfully. In case I don't however, and for the general case of this issue, I'm curious as to what the options are.

Comment: Does `FreeLibrary()` catch the exception, or does it propagate back to your code? If it's the latter case, I wouldn't be surprised if the next call to `LoadLibrary()` deadlocks because `FreeLibrary()` didn't get a chance to release the loader lock.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are after only unloading dll from the memory you can use

**[UnmapViewOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

providing bases address of your loaded dll as an argument.

### Example:

```
HINSTANCE hInst = LoadLibrary( "path_to_dll" );

if( !FreeLibrary( hInst ) )
{
   fprintf( stderr, "Couldn't unload library. Error Code: %02X\n. Attempting to unmap...", GetLastError() );
   if( !UnmapViewOfFile( hInst ) )
   { 
     fprintf( stderr, "Couldn't unmap the file! Error Code: %02X\n", GetLastError( ) );
   }
}
```

Or if it's a library that you didn't explicitly load (e.g. a library dependency that was loaded by a library that you loaded) and you don't have the handle, then use [GetModuleHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
HINSTANCE hInst = GetModuleHandle( "dllname_you_didn't_load" );
if( hInst != NULL )
{
   if( !UnmapViewOfFile( hInst ) )
   { 
     fprintf( stderr, "Couldn't unmap the file! Error Code: %02X\n", GetLastError( ) );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is only one possible solution - interop with dll through dedicated thread. So in time you need to unload dll you just exit (or may be kill) that thread and all associated with it resources will be freed. In this case you are not guaranteed about memory leaks, but I suggest this solution as temporary, till 3d party fixes bugs in dll

Comment: I think this solution may work if you have the option to limit the interaction with the lib to a subset of threads (ideally 1) and kill/restart that thread when an unload is necessary. Unfortunately for me, this library is utilized across numerous threads in my application that are co-operating and changing that structure would be brutal.

Comment: Zach Burlingame: Yes, my solution is not appropriate for you. For now I cant see any other solution except wait until bug would be fixed

Comment: Good idea, but that doesn't work with threads. You would need to use a child process that works like a wrapper/proxy for plugins. This would limit the problem to crashing the child process, not the main one.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the issue you're experience, but in case it is:

When using linker support for run-time dynamic linking, don't forget to use the [/Delay:Unload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96c1b5cf.aspx) argument.