# Should FreeLibrary be called at the end of the program?

Tags: c++, c++11, dll, loadlibrary

I haven't found this in the documentation: if I need a DLL handler until the end of the program, should I still call `FreeLibrary` before my caller program ends, or it's not required?

Comment: The dupe is a different story - it's about handling resource cleanup in a DLL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is best practice to *always* call `FreeLibrary` for any corresponding `LoadLibrary` call. However, skipping that call and just ending your program will likely not cause any serious issues, as terminating the calling process would appear to have the same effect as reducing the 'reference count' for your DLL (as calling `FreeLibrary` will do).

From the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-freelibrary) (bolding mine):

> The reference count is decremented each time the `FreeLibrary` or
> `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` function is called for the module. When a
> module's reference count reaches zero ***or the process terminates***, the
> system unloads the module from the address space of the process.
> Before unloading a library module, the system enables the module to
> detach from the process by calling the module's DllMain function, if
> it has one, with the DLL_PROCESS_DETACH value. Doing so gives the
> library module an opportunity to clean up resources allocated on
> behalf of the current process. After the entry-point function returns,
> the library module is removed from the address space of the current
> process.

One reason why it is best to *explicitly* call `FreeLibrary()` is that you can then deal with the situation if/when that call returns a failure (i.e. zero) status. The details of exactly how or why your DLL would not unload properly are beyond the scope of this answer, but you may find this discussion helpful: [What to do when FreeLibrary API call fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6153401/10871073)

Another reason would be that any future developers of your code may not realize that you are using program termination to *implicitly* unload the DLL and that, in some circumstances, could cause issues further down the road.

Comment: You might want to describe why it is "best practice" (I mean it is, but saying "best practice" without saying why is sometimes  unconvincing)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Very good point! (I was actually thinking about adding something, so thanks for reminding me.) See edit.